# Django 3.1: Development implication of creating a custom dashboard instead of using Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-3.0, django-3.1

I am a novice in Django.
I am just wondering why most developers would create separate dashboards to login and logout to perform all the CRUD functions. Why go through all that trouble instead of using the shipped Admin panel and create your users and assign permissions/roles to them to perform basically all the CRUD functions.

Comment: The django admin interface is tightly coupled to the django model structure and database. This is nice for developers. But for good user expirence, you very often need to combine features and data from several django models in one screen. This is hard to do using the django admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The admin panel functionality is limited and making changes can be burdensome. The admin panel is useful out of the box for an admin who needs access to database-level information, but for enterprise solutions I often find myself building custom dashboards as you suggest. The nice thing about django is that the structure makes any code you write highly reusable - in fact I've only written one custom dashboard and have reused it across all my various projects with great success!